# Launch device twitter settings from objective-c iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

How can i launch the twitter settings on the Device from my app with objective-c?

I am working on an app that shares a link on twitter, i am using the SLComposeViewController and it works, but when the Twitter app is not installed and no Twitter account is configured on settings it does nothing.

I want to show an alert inviting the user to log in on twitter to be able to share the link, when the user taps on a button the app should launch the Twitter settings on the device.

I have been reading that using the url scheme like this is not allowed since iOS 5.1

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];
```

I read it is only allowed to launch your app settings with this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

But i have found in some apps that it actually opens the Twitter settings like this one:

[screenshot of meme generator app that opens twitter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOACm.jpg)

Do you know how to do this?

Here is the code i use for the SLComposeViewController:

```
- (IBAction)twitterAction:(id)sender {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    activityView.center=self.view.center;
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];


 if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

SLComposeViewController *composerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

[composerSheet setInitialText:@"text to post"];
[composerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urltoshare.com"]];
[composerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"postimage.JPG"]];
[composerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
  [activityView stopAnimating];

  switch (result) {
    case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
      NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
         // some code ...
      break;
    case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
    [self changeSharedStatus];
      NSLog(@"Post Sucessful");
        // some code ...
      break;

    default:
      break;
     }
}];

    [self presentViewController:composerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}else {
/*  code to show the alert that invites the user to open settings */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the app that you found opens the Twitter settings,
it's because when you ask iOS to "create" a tweet, if there is no account setup in iOS, iOS will show you up this alertview asking you if you want to go in the setting for adding a twitter account to iOS.

So if you call SLComposeViewController the code is going to trigger this alertview if there is no twitter account in iOS:

```
SLComposeViewController *controllerSLC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[controllerSLC setInitialText:@"text"];
[self presentViewController:controllerSLC animated:YES completion:nil];
```